# Is there a way to find out what threads are launched from which shared object libraries in an embedded application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, embedded-linux, profiler

I am in the process of profiling an embedded application created using QtCreator, which is running on an old Linux distribution. I have been able to use Intel Vtune remotely on the physical device to collect profiling information. However, I notice that the application launches hundreds of threads which are mostly idle throughout the application. Is there a way to know what threads are launched from what shared object library?

I have tried with different profilers like vtune, advisor, valgrind, and gprof. I found that none of them provide this information.

Can anyone please help me with a way using which I can get this info?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using a debugger. If `lldb` is usable on your target platform, you could save these instructions to a file (for the sake of the example, `thread-backtraces.lldb`:

```
break set -n pthread_create
break command add 1
thread backtrace
process continue
DONE

process launch
```

and then run

```
lldb -b -s thread-backtraces.lldb -- path/to/your/exec -some -flags
```

which will start `lldb` in batch/script mode. The file above contains instructions to break whenever `pthread_create` is called (assuming that your platform uses `pthreads`), and automatically print a backtrace using a breakpoint command. This might give you a lot of output, which you might want to analyze with a script rather than manually. Its usefulness might also depend on compilation options (debug info, optimization level, frame pointer etc.).

The same can be achieved with `gdb`.